# How can I retrieve Cocoa enum values by name in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I am writing a MacOS window application in pure C++ using `objc/objc-runtime.h` as an experiment. I am able to open and display an `NSWindow`, however when calling the `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` method, I've been having to manually enter the enum values `styleMask` and `backing` as `int`s based on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowstylemask?language=objc).

This obviously isn't ideal, even if the enum values won't change (will they?), because I have to look up the documentation each time I want to change the value. Is there a way to retrieve enum values such as from `NSWindowStyleMask` using the objc runtime library? Or is there a plain C header that i can include which contains these definitions?

The alternative would be to define the enum myself but I would prefer not to do that

Thanks B)

Answer (score 0):

Might help, it's not quite "pure" C++:

1. Write a C++ file with the extension `.mm`, which is Objective-C++. This will compile C++ allowing for Objective-C constructs which allows...
2. `#include <Cocoa.Cocoa.h>` to get the enums you want
3. Compile with Clang

If you try to include `Cocoa.h` in a `.cpp` file you will get errors as you probably found out.

You can of course use your C++ functions/classes etc. defined in a `.mm` from a `.cpp`, it *is* C++.

HTH